# Trying to use Gtk.Application with python, but failing to handle open

Tags: python, gtk3

I am trying to have a Gtk.Application which stays unique and handles opening files. I am using python 2.7.3 on Ubuntu 12.04 with Gtk3 (fairly new to both python and Gtk)

The application runs fine without parameters, but it fails to get the file list when I run it trying to open a file. Here is the code, as minimalistic as I could make it:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
from gi.repository import Gtk, Gio

def do_open(app, files, *hint):
    print(app)
    print(files)
    print(hint)

def do_activate(app):
    print "activate"

test = Gtk.Application(application_id="a.b", flags=Gio.ApplicationFlags.HANDLES_OPEN)
test.set_inactivity_timeout(10000)
test.connect("open", do_open)
test.connect("activate", do_activate)
test.run(sys.argv)
```

When I run the program without arguments it just prints "activate", which is fine. When I run it with a parameter (like ./test.py test.py) I get the following:

```
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gi/types.py:43: Warning: g_value_get_boxed: assertion `G_VALUE_HOLDS_BOXED (value)' failed
return info.invoke(*args, **kwargs)
<Application object at 0x1c75230 (GtkApplication at 0x1cba0b0)>
[]
(1, '')
```

Does anyone understand why that assertion is failing and why I am getting an empty list of files?

As common as this task appears to be, I couldn't find any working example online either.

Answer (score 4):

There is a bug in PyGObject.  It is already reported in GNOME Bugzilla, check the bug report titled "[Does not handle GFile in signal arguments](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=678673)".

**Update**: The bug was fixed in 2013. No more assertion and it returns the list of files (GFiles). In other words, the code works as expected (at least using 3.14):

```
$ python test.py test.py
<Application object at 0x7fcaf18f5d20 (GtkApplication at 0x11892b0)>
[<__main__.GLocalFile object at 0x7fcaf18a6050 (GLocalFile at 0x11aea00)>]
(1, '')
```

Comment: Thanks! I suspected it was a bug. The only workaround I could find now is to use HANDLES_COMMAND_LINE and do it manually.